# configurable product don't show the discount

Tags: configurable-product

Simple products with configurable products linked to it, only show the special price as the price and not as discount compared the old price

Somehow an idea?

Comment: can you share some code how are you displaying price?

Comment: Where to find ? Here you see a simple without config product showing discount right: https://www.takoda.shop/en/stout-dog-tag-necklace-brass.html and here it is with config products showing wrong: https://www.takoda.shop/en/rainbow-rain-coat.html TY @AkhileshPatel